# Pop up/ child window property "closed" is always true when the window is actually open in IE 11 and other lower versions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, childwindow

// open new pop up window

```
this.childWindow = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");   


this.childWindow.document.write("<p>Loading..</p>");

this.childWindow.focus();
```

// submit form to cross origin domain from the pop up

```
this.childWindow.document.write("<form name='xform' method='POST' action='" + this.url + "' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='msg' id='xml'></input><input class='form-control' type='submit' id='formSubmit' style='display:none' ></input></form>");   

this.childWindow.document.getElementById('xml').value = response.message;

this.childWindow.document.getElementById('formSubmit').click();
```

// window closed event

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {

  if (this.childWindow && this.childWindow.closed) {

 // logic here when window closed

    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for showing interest. The whole code is really complex.  We are using angular 4. The form action is confidential.

Comment: Thank you for showing interest. The whole code is really complex.  We are using angular 4 for web app client. The form action url is confidential.  The web app is loaded in iframe of local html file. Then open a child window and submit a form.  When the child window is closed detect the event in the main window. The issue was resolved in IE when local html was hosted in a remote server. However it is not supported in edge. Share your insights.